# single digit addition questions

Tags: python, python-3.x, addition

im trying to build a program that will take an integer n as input and then ask n single-digit addition questions. The numbers to be added should be chosen randomly from the range [0,9](i.e., 0 to 9 inclusive). THe user will enter the answer when prompted. the function should print 'correct' for correct answers and 'incorrect' for incorrect answers. After n questions, the function should print the number of correct answers.

```
>>>add(2)
8 + 2 =
Enter answer: 10
correct.
8 + 4 =
Enter answer: 5
Incorrect.
You got 1 correct answer out of 2
```

the code I got so far is:

```
import random

def game(n):
    dig1 = random.randrange(0,10)
    dig2 = random.randrange(0,10)
    for i in range(n):
        print (dig1, '+', dig2, '=')
        answer = eval(input('Enter Answer: '))
        if answer == dig1 + dig2:
            print ('Correct.')
        else:
            print ('Incorrect.')
```

Comment: What have you learned about Python looping constructs so far?

Comment: well, i was thinking about a while loop, but i still dont see how I can condition the while loop to n

Comment: Any other loop constructs you can think of?

Comment: a for loop? or are you talking about recursion?

Comment: Do you know about the `range()` function and what it does?

Comment: What do you think will happen when you use that?

Comment: so for every i in n, i would get a question printed?

Comment: That sounds an awful lot like what you were looking for, doesn't it? Why don't you try it out?

Comment: heheh thank you ( im kinda new to python)

Comment: I guessed; loops are pretty basic constructs. You may want to scan through the [python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html) for this kind of information. :-)

Comment: i just updated my code with a for loop and range function, but i still can't get it to generate n different questions, it only generates one question. Could you look at my code to see if you can find any problems or changes I can make?

Comment: i figured it out! the dig1 and dig2 needs to be in the loop :)

Comment: Thak you Martijn, very good teachings maan!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create *new* random digits each loop:

```
def game(n):
    for i in range(n):
        dig1 = random.randrange(0,10)
        dig2 = random.randrange(0,10)
        print (dig1, '+', dig2, '=')
        answer = eval(input('Enter Answer: '))
        if answer == dig1 + dig2:
            print ('Correct.')
        else:
            print ('Incorrect.')
```

Answer (score 0):

I have added the requested statistics logic and fixed the same loop problem as Martijn pointed out

```
import random 

def game(n):
    rights = 0 
    for z in xrange(n):
        dig1 = random.randrange(0,10)
        dig2 = random.randrange(0,10)
        print (dig1, '+', dig2, '=')
        answer = input ('Enter Answer: ')
        if answer == dig1 + dig2:
            print ('Correct')
        else:
            rights += 1
            print ('Incorrect')

    print "You got {rights} right in {n} tries".format(rights=rights, n=n)
```